# CDbException: The DB query must contain the "from" portion

Tags: database

Seeing the above error, somewhat sporadically, and can't seem to track it down.

Here's the full log entry:

```
2014/07/03 15:17:22 [error] [exception.CDbException] exception 'CDbException' with message 'The DB query must contain the "from" portion.' in /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php:566
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(160): CDbCommand->buildQuery(Array)
#1 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(484): CDbCommand->getText()
#2 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(415): CDbCommand->queryInternal('fetch', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php(410): CDbCommand->queryRow()
#4 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php(146): Craft\AppBehavior->getInfo('edition')
#5 [internal function]: Craft\AppBehavior->getEdition()
#6 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php(261): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/services/LocalizationService.php(111): CComponent->__call('getEdition', Array)
#8 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/services/LocalizationService.php(111): Craft\WebApp->getEdition()
#9 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/services/LocalizationService.php(141): Craft\LocalizationService->getSiteLocales()
#10 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/services/LocalizationService.php(154): Craft\LocalizationService->getPrimarySiteLocale()
#11 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(824): Craft\LocalizationService->getPrimarySiteLocaleId()
#12 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(291): Craft\WebApp->_getTargetLanguage()
#13 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/framework/i18n/CMessageSource.php(83): Craft\WebApp->getLanguage()
#14 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/framework/YiiBase.php(585): CMessageSource->translate('yii', 'The DB query mu...', NULL)
#15 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(566): YiiBase::t('yii', 'The DB query mu...')
#16 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(160): CDbCommand->buildQuery(Array)
#17 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(484): CDbCommand->getText()
#18 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(415): CDbCommand->queryInternal('fetch', Array, Array)
#19 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php(410): CDbCommand->queryRow()
#20 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php(371): Craft\AppBehavior->getInfo('maintenance')
#21 [internal function]: Craft\AppBehavior->isInMaintenanceMode()
#22 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php(261): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#23 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(145): CComponent->__call('isInMaintenance...', Array)
#24 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(145): Craft\WebApp->isInMaintenanceMode()
#25 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#26 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/craft/app/index.php(196): CApplication->run()
#27 /var/www/topsecret.co.uk/web/index.php(17): require_once('/var/www/topse...')
#28 {main}
```

Looking through that I'm not seeing any references to any custom plugins or templates so wonder if it's a bug...

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traced the error back to the `from` function in Yii's `craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php`:

```
$tables=preg_split('/\s*,\s*/u',trim($tables),-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The [`preg_split` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) states "if matching fails, an array with a single element containing the input string will be returned" but I was just getting an empty array.

This made me suspicious of what the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag was hiding, sure enough without it I got an array with one empty string in it, as if there was a match.

Some trial and error later and adding the [`PCRE_UTF8` modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `u` to the `preg_split` patterns seemed to solve the problem.

Unfortunately can't explain what's causing the encoding issues yet.

Comment: Curious... what's the charset and collation of your database set to?  Specifically the craft_info table, since that's the one that seems to be causing the issues.

Comment: @BradBell `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci`, looks correct to me?

I can't explain the irregular occurrence of it. Intermittence I can conceivably blame on caching, but it only effecting homepage requests...?

Comment: Yeah, that looks correct... really strange.  Have you tried re-saving all your template files with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @BradBell the templates are reported as a mix of `us-ascii` and `utf-8` (using `file -I`). From what I gather `us-ascii` is a subset of `utf-8` though?

Comment: Not entirely sure... probably worth using something like Sublime and explicitly resaving as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

That actually looks like it might be a bug.  Can you send a database dump as well as a zip of your craft/storage/runtime/logs folder over to support@buildwithcraft.com so we can investigate?